# Error: Content is not allowed in prolog при подключении БД в assets

Tags: java, android

Вообщем,создал я бд через программу sqlitebrowoser, добавил в папку assets и при компиляции вываливается такая ошибка,если бд убрать из папки assets то данна ошибка пропадает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Лог ошибок:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet810Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable810Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
D:\Android Project\Virtual\POKEMON\POKEMON\Pokemon\app\src\main\res\assets\coordinate.db
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> D:\Android Project\Virtual\POKEMON\POKEMON\Pokemon\app\src\main\res\assets\coordinate.db:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 19.908 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Класс БД:

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.pokemongo.pokemon.database/databases/";
public static final String DB_NAME = "coordinate";
public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";

private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
static final String TABLE = "users";


public SQLiteDatabase database;
private Context myContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    this.myContext=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {

}

public void create_db() {
    {
        InputStream myInput = null;
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                //получаем локальную бд как поток
                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Путь к новой бд
                String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

                // Открываем пустую бд
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
}
public void open() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
```

}

**UPD:**
изменил в классе activity метод,вылеате на курсорсе:

```
  private void randomCoordinate() {


   ArrayList<Double> latitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> longitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    String queryLatitude = "SELECT * FROM latitude ORDER BY  column DESC LIMIT 1";
    String queryLongitude = "SELECT * FROM longitude ORDER BY  column DESC LIMIT 1";

    Cursor cLatitude  =  sqlHelper.database.rawQuery(queryLatitude, null);
    Cursor cLongitude  =  sqlHelper.database.rawQuery(queryLongitude, null);
    if(cLatitude != null)
    {
        while(cLatitude.moveToNext()){
            latitudesAr.add(cLatitude.getDouble(cLatitude.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LATITUDE)));
        }
    }
    if(cLongitude != null)
    {
        while(cLongitude.moveToNext()){
            longitudesAr.add(cLatitude.getDouble(cLatitude.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LONGITUDE)));
        }
    }
    //получаем рандомно выбранные индексы
    Random r = new Random();
    int indexLatitude = r.nextInt(latitudesAr.size());
    int indexLongitude = r.nextInt(longitudesAr.size());
    //присваиваем переменным
    mMyLatitude = latitudesAr.get(indexLatitude);
    mMyLongitude = longitudesAr.get(indexLongitude);

}
```

вызываю в oncreate

может ошибочно создаю курсор?
бза лежит по адресу:
assets/database
Обновил класс BD:

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.pokemongo.pokemon.database/databases/";
    public static final String DB_NAME = "coordinate.db";
    public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";

    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "users";


    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public  final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {

    }

    public void create_db() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
    public void open() throws SQLException {
        String dbPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
}

т
```

аблица бд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в название базы добавить расширение:

```
public static final String DB_NAME = "coordinate.db";
```

**UPD**
это делается вот так:

```
private void copyDatabaseFromAssets(Context context) throws IOException {
  InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
  OutputStream outputStream = new  FileOutputStream(context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME));

  byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
  while (inputStream.read(buffer) > 0) {
     outputStream.write(buffer);
  }

  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();
  inputStream.close();
}
```

**UPD 2**

```
 public SQLiteDatabase database;//это никуда не годится
```

нужно пользоваться методом `getWritableDatabase()` вашего `DatabaseHelper`

это будет где-то так:

```
Cursor cLatitude = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(queryLatitude, null);
```

Comment: не помогло,может нельзя содержать бд в данной папке?

Comment: @ s_klepcha
создал в каталоге res папку raw и переместил туда бд,ошибка не вылезла,только как теперь указывать через курсор путь к этой бд

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуйте это решение

Comment: @ s_klepcha
так у меня же реализован данный метод в классе хелпер,я ен опнимаю,Как мне получить бд
Cursor cLatitude  =  sqlHelper.database.rawQuery(queryLatitude, null);
        Cursor cLongitude  =  sqlHelper.database.rawQuery(queryLongitude, null);
если я указываю так,то получаю null и вылет из приложения

Comment: нет, не так - вместо myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);  нужно myInput =new  FileOutputStream(context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME));

Comment: опять обновил ответ

Comment: @ s_klepcha
буду пробовать,потом отпишусь